# javax.net.ssl.keystore vs javax.net.ssl.keyStore is the same or different

Tags: ssl

Currently we are using parameter javax.net.ssl.keystore to define a keystore, but I see it is defined as javax.net.ssl.keyStore in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_MQ_Enterprise/7.1/html/Security_Guide/files/SSL-SysProps.html.

I am not sure whether it's working fine or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is defined as `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` in the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores), which trumps any other documentation on the subject.

It isn't the same as `javax.net.ssl.keystore,` which doesn't exist. System properties are case-sensitive in Java.